# How to prefer to wrap text in one column before break-all in another?

Tags: css, html-table, overflow, word-wrap, word-break

Finally I think I've found a question that nobody has exactly asked before. I have a table with two columns. The first column might sometimes have a reallyreallyreallylongword. The second column always has many short words which wrap well. If I apply word-break:break-all to the first column and then shrink my browser window, the columns stay 50/50 when I would prefer to wrap all the short words in the second column before doing the ugly break-all wrapping in the first column.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="word-break:break-all;">reallyreallyreallyreallylongword</td>
    <td>Here are a lot of short words that wrap nicely</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to wrap all possible wrappable words in all columns before resorting to the ugly break-all, but still going to it as a last resort to prevent overflow. It doesn't matter which columns end up wider.

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing sir! All words are already wrapped in the columns by the table, table row and td, so im not sure what you mean there. With the columns are you trying to keep the one with long words as wide as possible at all times to prevent the word-break from happening for as long as possible? [im assuming this is to do with a responsive design?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I want to PRIORITIZE shrinking the cell with wrappable text, BEFORE doing the forced break of long words in the other cell.

Comment: ok i think i get you. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

So if you give the two columns a percentage width, with one larger than the other, the larger one will take longer before it starts having to shrink the text.

EG:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="widecolumn">reallyreallyreallyreallylongword</td>
         <td class="smallcolumn">Here are a lot of short words that wrap nicely</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    table {
      max-width:1000px;
      width:100%;
    }

    td {
      word-break:break-all;
    }
    td.widecolumn {
      width:65%;  
    }
    td.smallcolumn {
      width:35%;
    }
```

working example: https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/XPKPNZ